# How to bold all digits before period in a number?

Tags: css

I am trying to change the font size of a price value using the CSS below:

```
h2.bold.value::first-letter {
     font-size: 150%;
}
```

Unfortunately this is working only with single digit numbers before period like (9.99, 0.99). Is there a way in CSS to change the font-size for all digits before period (**10**.99, **18**.27, **190**.45 etc)?

Comment: "bold" is on font-weight sir. put a <span> in your decimal point. and style it differently with the rest.

Comment: yes but need to know if the values are dynamically generated or if static you can use this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uq6buk4x/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values are static/dynamic it doesnt matter just follow this format I suggest:

```
<p class="val"><span>9999</span>.<span>99</span></p>
```

in css

```
.val {
   //Overall style
}
.val span:first-child {
  //style digits before period
}
.val span:last-child {
  //style digits after period
}
```

in js to apply this, for example

```
x = '999.99';
x = str_replace(".","</span>.<span>",x);
x = '<p class="val"><span>' + x + '</span></p>;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to style numbers (decimal places, decimal separator, thousands separator, etc.) with pure css. Even JS solutions would be inaccurate. You normally solve this by using the span tag and styling it.

Answer (score 1):

using pseudo element `:after`

```css
div {
  font-size: 30px;
}
div:after {
  content: '.99';
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div>99</div>
```

or

```css
div{
    font-size:30px;
}
div:after{
    content:attr(data-content);
    font-size:15px;
}
```

```html
<div data-content=".99">99</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this without introducing an element that contains just the characters to be rendered in bold. It depends on the context whether you write markup for the element or generate the element dynamically with client-side JavaScript.

Using static markup, you could write e.g.

```
<b>10</b>.99
```

Some people may call that “semantically wrong”, but this is really the most reliable way to bold characters. A different approach is to use HTML markup like

```
<span class=int>10</span>.99
```

and the CSS code

```
.int { font-weight: bold }
```

Both ways require the availability of a bold typeface of the font being used. This is important especially when using Google Fonts and other downloadable fonts. If a bold typeface is not available, browsers usually apply fake bolding (algorithmic/synthetic bolding), with typographically inferior results.

Note. Setting `font-size` does not effect boldness, even though larger characters may look bolder when you compare them with smaller characters.